# How do I use Case When with 2 different variables?

Tags: sql

Ok I hope my question doesn't come out as silly. But I have a situation I have to use case when.
i have a list of 
- item
- purchase delivery date
- buyer
I have a,b,c,d,e buyers. Among those, only a,b,c are valid buyer.

Now I want the result that shows case when buyer = a, b, c then purchase delivery date will be "mm/dd/yy" else purchase delivery date will be blank

In this case, purchase delivery and buyer are 2 different variables. How do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN buyer IN ('A','B','C') THEN dateColumn 
            ELSE NULL END AS DerivedColumn
FROM Table
...
```

When doing a `CASE` you must remember to keep all the possible branches returning a similar type.  For example, one branch returning a datetime and another returning a string/text is not going to work.  Obviously `NULL` works for all data types.